# MySQL REGEXP in where not finding expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have this query:

```
SELECT certREF,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(certREF,'-',-1) as UNSIGNED) as REF 
FROM certificatecatalog 
WHERE certREF is not null AND `certREF` REGEXP 'F[\d]+-[\d]+' 
ORDER BY REF DESC 
Limit 0,1
```

I have data rows in column certREF like:

```
F17-1257
F17-3546
F18-8854
F19-9854
```

I want to be able to pull the highest number after "F*number*-"

The regualar expression seems to work when i put it in one of those live regex testers.

However i'm getting an empty result set.

If someone could let me know where i'm going wrong :)

Thanks

Comment: Use `REGEXP '^F[0-9]+-[0-9]+$'` (see  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN3OG2/1)).

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is implicit conversion:

```
select max(substr(certRef, 2) + 0)
from certificatecatalog
where certRef like 'F%';
```

MySQL will convert the digits after the first `F` to a number, stopping at the first non-digit.  It then returns the maximum value.  Regular expressions are not needed for this.

EDIT:

If you want the part after the hyphen, then you can do either:

```
select max(substr(certRef, 5) + 0)
from certificatecatalog
where certRef like 'F%';
```

or:

```
select max(substring_index(certRef, '-', -1) + 0)
from certificatecatalog
where certRef like 'F%';
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry i perhaps needed to expand on the data in the table more, there are some with FE4-99, FR15-55, it's just the F on it's own i need.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `substr()` with `instr()` function as :

```
select max(substr(certREF,instr(certREF,'-')+1,length(certREF)))
       as maxNumber
  from certificatecatalog;

MAXNUMBER
  9854
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66a2c/1)